# Pygame Using Class to Randomize Image Placements

Tags: python, class, python-3.x, pygame

I'm creating a card/tile memory association game. It is a 4x4 grid of 100x100 pixel images, so 16 images in total are displayed (8 pairs).

For now all I want is for the images to be displayed in a grid in a random order each time the game is started, which I feel I am close to doing using shuffling them in a list in a class and then calling that class from the main function in the while loop.

Here is my code:

```
# Memory Tiles Game
# A Memory Game which users can flip tiles in and remember their placement to match
# all of the tiles 

import pygame, sys, time
from pygame.locals import *

# User-defined classes
class memorygame(object):
   def __init__(self):
      imagelist = [image1,image2,image3,image4,image5,image6,image7
                   image8,image9]
      shuffle.imagelist
      screen.blit(imagelist[0],(0,0))
      screen.blit(imagelist[1],(104,0))
      screen.blit(imagelist[2],(208,0))
      screen.blit(imagelist[3],(312,0))
      screen.blit(imagelist[4],(0,104))
      screen.blit(imagelist[5],(104,104))
      screen.blit(imagelist[6],(208,104))
      screen.blit(imagelist[7],(312,104))
      shuffle.imagelist
      screen.blit(imagelist[0],(0,208))
      screen.blit(imagelist[1],(104,208))
      screen.blit(imagelist[2],(208,208))
      screen.blit(imagelist[3],(312,208))
      screen.blit(imagelist[4],(0,312))
      screen.blit(imagelist[5],(104,312))
      screen.blit(imagelist[6],(208,312))
      screen.blit(imagelist[7],(312,312))






# User-defined functions

def main():

   black = (  0,  0, 0)
   white = (255,255,255)
   red = (100,  0,  0)
   green = (  0,153,  0)
   blue = (  0,  0,255)
   image1 = pygame.image.load('image0.bmp')
   image2 = pygame.image.load('image1.bmp')
   image3 = pygame.image.load('image2.bmp')
   image4 = pygame.image.load('image3.bmp')
   image5 = pygame.image.load('image4.bmp')
   image6 = pygame.image.load('image5.bmp')
   image7 = pygame.image.load('image6.bmp')
   image8 = pygame.image.load('image7.bmp')
   image9 = pygame.image.load('image8.bmp')
   w = 500
   h = 400
   screen = pygame.display.set_mode((w, h))
   screen.fill((white))
   running = 1

   # Initialize pygame
   pygame.init()

   # Set window size and title, and frame delay
   surfaceSize = (500, 400) # example window size
   windowTitle = 'Memory Game' # example title
   frameDelay = 0.02 # smaller is faster game

   # Create the window
   surface = pygame.display.set_mode(surfaceSize, 0, 0)
   pygame.display.set_caption(windowTitle)

   # create and initialize objects
   gameOver = False
   #center = [200, 200] # example - replace

   # Draw objects
   # The next line is an example - replace it
   #pygame.draw.circle(surface, pygame.Color('green'), center, 50, 0)

   # Refresh the display
   pygame.display.update()

   # Loop forever
   while True:
      # Check event
      event = pygame.event.poll()
      if event.type == QUIT:
         pygame.quit()
         sys.exit()
      screen.fill((black))
      class memorygame(object) 

      # Handle additional events

      # Update and draw objects for the next frame
      gameOver = update(center, surface)

      # Refresh the display
      pygame.display.update()

      # Set the frame speed by pausing between frames
      time.sleep(frameDelay)

main()
```

It doesn't seem to compile, and I am not sure why. I get a syntax error in the shell.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you forgot a comma at the end of the first line in the imagelist in your memorygame class. Changing that to

```
imagelist = [image1,image2,image3,image4,image5,image6,image7,
             image8,image9]
```

should fix the first syntax error.

Secondly, I'm not sure what you are trying to achieve with the line `class memorygame(object)` in your main loop. You probably want to create an instance of the class outside of the while loop and call a function that blits the images inside the while loop.

The image variables are local by the way, the memorygame class will not see them, unless you explicitly make them global variables, or pass them to the __init__ method of memorygame.

Besides, the way you're shuffling the imagelist isn't quite right. You should import random, and then call random.shuffle(imagelist) instead.